# Instantiate GameObject while Camera Moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on my 2D game where I have my main camera moving horizontally from left to right. Instead of instantiate all game objects at the start of the scene, I want to spawn them as the camera moves close to their x positions.
I have a JSON like this to store the position of each GO that need to be spawned during runtime:

```json
{
    "apple":{
        "xpos":13,
        "ypos":2
    },
    "banana":{
        "xpos":40,
        "ypos":2
    },
    "pear":{
        "xpos":25,
        "ypos":2
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to trigger the instantiation when the camera's x position is equal or greater than the x position of each of the items? Suppose the camera starts moving from a x position of 0. Thank you in advance!

Comment: use update() to check x ?

Comment: Do you mean putting a loop inside update to continuously check while the player moves the camera?

Comment: yes  ,  check on camera moving , and you can make some group to make performance better, not foreach all object every time.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

- Get the center of your screen (use an empty `gameObject` as a child of your camera or any other method of your suiting)
- In Update() method check the distance between `X position` of the `empty GO` and `xpos` of your `JSON` if the distance is in between `Screensize.x/2` and `(Screensize.x/2 + offset)` then `instantiate`.